# SymPy memory explosion when computing nullspace of a small matrix

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sympy

I am trying to find a basis for the nullspace of some matrix in Sympy.

I have the following code:

```
def get_null_space(vectors_list):
    A = sympy.Matrix(vectors_list).T
    return A.nullspace()
```

each element of `vectors_list` is a tuple of `SymPy.core.numbers`, the elements are 1,-1,0.

The matrix shape is (384, 120).

When running the code, it **uses all memory** (60GB), gets stuck and eventually crashes the kernel.

Setting
`os.environ["SYMPY_USE_CACHE"]="no"`
and 
`os.environ["SYMPY_INT_TRACE"]="no"`
did not make any change.

Numerically using NumPy's `svd` the nullspace is zero-dimensional.

I use sympy's latest version. What can I do to compute the nullspace symbolically?

Comment: The function body formatting is not right. Can you please correct that?

Comment: @SRC Sure. Now it's fine, I hope

Comment: caching is an import time decision.  If you want to disable it you must execute the line `os.environ["SYMPY_USE_CACHE"]="no"` before you import sympy.

Comment: The main sympy cache is a bounded lru cache so it shouldn't cause the issue you are seeing but there are other caching mechanisms floating around.  try `os.environ["SYMPY_TRACE_INT"]="no"` and see if that helps

Comment: @ptb Unfortunately, the memory keeps exploding.

Comment: You could try the sympy mailing list. They may have some suggestions on how to compute this.  It may be that sympy is treating your matrix as full.